# radial basis networks in RSNNS

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network

I am trying to understand how RBF networks works with RSNNS, and I have some doubts about the parameters in "nitFuncParams" and "learnFuncParams", I try this for example (this is the R code):*

```
X <- data.frame(x1=c(1,0,0,1),x2=c(1,1,0,0))
Y <- as.matrix(c(1,0,1,0),4,1)
library(RSNNS)
```

here, I use two centers and just one iteration

```
rbfn.model <- RSNNS::rbf(as.matrix(X,ncol=2),as.matrix(Y),         
                     size=2,    
                     maxit=1,
initFunc = "RBF_Weights",
initFuncParams = c(0, 0,0, 0.02, 0),
learnFunc = "RadialBasisLearning",
learnFuncParams = c(0,0,0.01,0,0),
updateFunc = "Topological_Order",
updateFuncParams = c(0),linOut=TRUE)
```

This is the prediction

```
rbf.network.pred <-predict(rbfn.model, X) 
rbf.network.pred

       [,1]
   [1,] 0.05882368
   [2,] 0.05805492
   [3,] 0.05805485
   [4,] 0.05882360
```

This is the additional information

```
extractNetInfo(rbfn.model)

## $infoHeader
##                 name               value
## 1       no. of units                   5
## 2 no. of connections                   6
## 3  no. of unit types                   0
## 4  no. of site types                   0
## 5  learning function RadialBasisLearning
## 6    update function   Topological_Order
## 
## $unitDefinitions
##   unitNo   unitName   unitAct  unitBias        type posX posY posZ
## 1      1    Input_1 1.0000000 0.0000000  UNIT_INPUT    1    0    0
## 2      2    Input_2 0.0000000 0.0000000  UNIT_INPUT    2    0    0
## 3      3 Hidden_2_1 1.0000000 1.0000000 UNIT_HIDDEN    1    2    0
## 4      4 Hidden_2_2 0.3678795 1.0000000 UNIT_HIDDEN    2    2    0
## 5      5   Output_1 0.0611404 0.0388499 UNIT_OUTPUT    1    4    0
##                actFunc      outFunc sites
## 1         Act_Identity Out_Identity      
## 2         Act_Identity Out_Identity      
## 3     Act_RBF_Gaussian Out_Identity      
## 4     Act_RBF_Gaussian Out_Identity      
## 5 Act_IdentityPlusBias Out_Identity      
## 
## $fullWeightMatrix
##            Input_1 Input_2 Hidden_2_1 Hidden_2_2   Output_1
## Input_1          0       0          1          1 0.00000000
## Input_2          0       0          0          1 0.00000000
## Hidden_2_1       0       0          0          0 0.01415128
## Hidden_2_2       0       0          0          0 0.02212468
## Output_1         0       0          0          0 0.00000000
```

I read the manual from SNNS, and use the formulas but I don't obtain the same answers (weights)

*weights=pseudoinverse(t(G)%*%G + lamda*C)%*%t(G)%*%Y*

where  lamda= 0.01,
G is a matrix that contains for example exp(-0.02*||xi-ti||^2) , where t are the two centers in this case 1,1 and 1,0
C is a matrix that use the distance between the centers for example exp(-0.02*||ti-tj||^2) 
Y is the output

**Here we can see that my first weights are 0.01415128 and 0.02212468,also my bias in the otuput is 0.0388499, How I obtain this first values??, and also when I use 2 iterations I use this formula to actualize the bias in the output neuron: b(i+1) =
b(i) + lambda* sum(error), and it works but w(i+1) = w(i) + lambda* sum(error)*centers does not for the weights, please someone can help me?**

This is the aditional information in the  iteration = 2

```
extractNetInfo(rbfn.model)
$infoHeader
            name               value
1       no. of units                   5
2 no. of connections                   6
3  no. of unit types                   0
4  no. of site types                   0
5  learning function RadialBasisLearning
6    update function   Topological_Order

$unitDefinitions
  unitNo   unitName   unitAct   unitBias        type posX posY posZ
1      1    Input_1 1.0000000 0.00000000  UNIT_INPUT    1    0    0
2      2    Input_2 0.0000000 0.00000000  UNIT_INPUT    2    0    0
3      3 Hidden_2_1 1.0000000 0.02000000 UNIT_HIDDEN    1    2    0
4      4 Hidden_2_2 0.9801987 0.02000000 UNIT_HIDDEN    2    2    0
5      5   Output_1 0.1107717 0.03766243 UNIT_OUTPUT    1    4    0
               actFunc      outFunc sites
1         Act_Identity Out_Identity      
2         Act_Identity Out_Identity      
3     Act_RBF_Gaussian Out_Identity      
4     Act_RBF_Gaussian Out_Identity      
5 Act_IdentityPlusBias Out_Identity  

$fullWeightMatrix
           Input_1 Input_2 Hidden_2_1 Hidden_2_2   Output_1
Input_1          0       0          1          1 0.00000000
Input_2          0       0          0          1 0.00000000
Hidden_2_1       0       0          0          0 0.03691628
Hidden_2_2       0       0          0          0 0.03692412
Output_1         0       0          0          0 0.00000000
```

Comment: I think that's also the only thing I would be doing. Going back to the original SNNS manual to understand the formulas. Another thing that you can try is have a look at the code. In the package source, have a look at src/learn_f.cpp The radial basis function code starts around line 3275.